# multiple text files - need to extract certain piece of information

Tags: batch-file, text, extract

**System: Win7**

Hi guys,

I got about 60.000 htm files going from text_1.htm to text_60000.htm. Each of of those files contains a line indicating the title of it which can be uniquely located by searching for:

```html
title="*"></a></div>
```

There are many instances of

```
title="*"
```

in each file, so searching for that expression alone is out of the question.

I'd like to rename the files to their appropriate titles. The program I use to rename files can batch rename files by using a .txt file, containing the original file name and the new file name separated by a semi-colon, like this:

text_1.htm:TitleA.htm

text_2.htm:TitleB.htm

...

text_60000.htm:TitleABCDE.htm

-

It would be highly appreciated if one of you could offer a solution  in order for me to get this one .txt file I need to rename my files.

I am looking forward to your replies.

Comment: This task requires a lot of coding. HTML files are often encoded in UTF-8 and therefore the title could contain UTF-8 encoded characters. Also the title could contain characters not allowed for file names which must be filtered out or substituted. All references to the files must be also updated. Special use cases like no page title, or title is an empty string, or two pages with same title must be also taken into account. Long titles should be truncated for file name. See help topic [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) What do you have written so far?

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is not a free coding service.  Normally we don't write scripts on request.  We only help you fix problems with your own scripts and provide tips and tricks to improve your code.

Be that as it may, I found your challenge interesting, and decided to accept.  Here, save this with a .bat extension and see whether it does what you want.

#### simpler method:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.htm) do for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" ^< "%%~fI"'
) do echo ren "%%~fI" "%%~A%%~xI"
rem // Remove "echo" above when satisfied that the files
rem // will be renamed correctly.

goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile');
DOM.write(WSH.StdIn.ReadAll());

for (var el = DOM.getElementsByTagName('*'), i = el.length; --i;)
    if (el[i].title)
        if (el[i].parentNode.nodeName == 'A')
            if (el[i].parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'DIV') break;

DOM.close(WSH.Echo(el[i].title));
```

Edit: Since you've got 60,000 files to rename, it's probably better to have the Wscript FSO object enumerate the files and only launch `cscript` once (rather than once per file).

#### much faster method:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off & setlocal
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"
goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    fso = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    dir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WSH.ScriptFullName);

function getTitle() {
    for (var el = DOM.getElementsByTagName('*'), i = el.length; --i;)
        if (el[i].title)
            if (el[i].parentNode.nodeName == 'A')
                if (el[i].parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'DIV') break;
    return el[i].title;
}

for (var col = new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder(dir).files); !col.atEnd(); col.moveNext()) {
    var from = col.item();
    if (/\.html?$/i.test(from)) {
        var htmlfile = fso.OpenTextFile(from, 1);
        DOM.write(htmlfile.ReadAll());
        htmlfile.Close();
        var to = dir + '\\' + getTitle() + '.' + fso.GetExtensionName(from);
        WSH.Echo(from + ' -> ' + to);
        // fso.MoveFile(from, to);
        // Uncomment the previous line when you're ready to rename.
    }
}

DOM.close();
```